# I have an error "Dll load error" while using Hybridizer in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, hybridizer

I am using Hybridizer for the first time. I am using Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019, CUDA 10.1 and Hybridizer 1.3.0 "Released Sep. 5th 2019". Although I have followed their steps, I keep getting the same error:

> Dll load error when loading Hello_World_CUDA.dll: 126

whenever I try to make any simple code to test it like this:

```
using System;
using Hybridizer.Runtime.CUDAImports;
public class Hello_World
{
    [EntryPoint]
    public static void Hello()
    {
        Console.Out.Write("Hello from GPU");
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        cuda.DeviceSynchronize();
        HybRunner runner = HybRunner.Cuda().SetDistrib(1, 2);
        runner.Wrap(new Hello_World()).Hello();
    }
}
```

even when using their examples without any change.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you verified the CUDA project has also been built and that solution platform is x64 ?

Comment: Have done both. The same problem.

Comment: You should file an issue on github, and/or report to the support email.

Comment: It seems they had this problem for months now. https://github.com/altimesh/hybridizer-basic-samples/issues/66

Comment: It would help to get the full exception stack, and the complete output log. Could you provide this ?

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot please follow the three following steps:

1. Check file exists and can be loaded from current directory
2. Make sure dll can be loaded using [LoadLibrary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya)
3. Verify symbol can be found using [GetProcAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getprocaddress)

To facilitate your investigation, please find below code to run these assertions

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Hybridizer.Runtime.CUDAImports;

public class Hello_World
{
    [EntryPoint]
    public static void Hello()
    {
        Console.Out.Write("Hello from GPU");
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "LoadLibraryA", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string name);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "FormatMessage", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern int FormatMessage(int dwFlags, IntPtr lpSource, int dwMessageId, int dwLanguageId, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] char[] data, uint dwSize, IntPtr args);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetProcAddress", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string symbol);

    static unsafe string ErrorToString(int er)
    {
        char[] buffer = new char[2048];
        int res = FormatMessage(0x00001000, // FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM
                IntPtr.Zero, er,
                0x0409, // US language -- in case of issue, replace with 0
                buffer, 2048, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (res == 0)
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Cannot format message - Error : {0}", res));
        string resstring;
        fixed (char* ptr = &buffer[0])
        {
            resstring = new string(ptr);
        }
        return resstring;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        // Trouble-shooting

        // print execution directory
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Current directory : {0}", Environment.CurrentDirectory);
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Size of IntPtr = {0}", Marshal.SizeOf(IntPtr.Zero));

        // first, make sure file exists
        string path = @"Troubleshooting_CUDA.dll"; // replace with actual dll name - you can read that on the output of the build
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Dll could not be found in path, please verify dll is located in the appropriate directory that LoadLibrary may find it");
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }

        // make sure it can be loaded -- open DLL in depends to missing troubleshoot dependencies (may be long to load)
        IntPtr lib = LoadLibrary(path);
        if (lib == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            int code = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            string er = ErrorToString(code);
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Dll could not be loaded : {0}", er);
            Environment.Exit(2);
        }

        // finally try to get the proc address -- open DLL in depends to see list of symbols (may be long to load)
        IntPtr procAddress = GetProcAddress(lib, "Hello_Worldx46Hello_ExternCWrapper_CUDA");
        if (procAddress == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            int code = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            string er = ErrorToString(code);
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Could not find symbol in dll : {0}", er);
            Environment.Exit(3);
        }

        cuda.DeviceSynchronize();
        HybRunner runner = HybRunner.Cuda().SetDistrib(1, 2);
        runner.Wrap(new Hello_World()).Hello();
    }
}
```

If it fails at first step, you may need to change output directory of the CUDA satellite project, and/or execution directory of your application.

Should it fail at second step, you want to verify you execute in x64 (size of IntPtr should be 8), and that dll loads. Dependency walker, you may find [here](http://dependencywalker.com/), is a great tool for this purpose, you want the x64 version. *NOTE: loading may be very long*.

Should it fail at third step, look-up the symbol name with depends, maybe your CUDA satellite project is not up to date.

Comment: As I expected, it was the first step. I don't find this "Hello_World_CUDA.dll" file. How it should be generated?

Comment: By building the satellite project (CUDA)

Comment: How can I do this in C#? I honestly don't get it.

Comment: The satellite project is a vcxproj, hence a C++ project which depends on CUDA. To get started, here is a decent entry point https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/building-and-cleaning-projects-and-solutions-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Comment: I tried to do this, but it keeps giving me different errors as "Internal Error" "The path specified for SourceFile at 'D:\Hybridizer\Hello_World_CUDA\hybridizer-generated-sources\hybridizer.wrappers.cu' does not exist". I think I will give up on Hybridizer.